# A crossword with a single clue #2

Tags: crosswords

I have prepared you a new crossword with numbers. The words include: English words, phrases, proper names, abbreviations that could be found online.

**In blue: Reversed luminous plasma likes dark places.**

[image: crossword]

Here is a text version of the crossword:

```
10  14  19  10  11  14  3   1       10  9       
1   2   3   5   6   6       14  7   19  6   5   
14  3       2   15  11  3   10      3   5   3   1
10  19  10  15  2       18  3   8       6   12  6
21  6   11  10      5   6   11  10  19      3   11
10  14  6       22  2   10      1   2   19  6   10
11      15  2   10  11      10  1   1   2   5   14
14  5   3   17  16      1   3   8       5   6   6
9   3   17  17  20  8       5   2   22  6       1
3   18      20      10  10      5   10  14  1   
11  6   3   19  10  5   15  1   14  5   2   11  4
    5   2   14  14  6   11          16      3   
6   1   14      10  14  6   10  1   6       8   3
5       10  14  15  2   1   8   9   6   5   6   
2   13      7   10      3   2       8   7   5   2
1   10  12  10  11  11  10  9           6   1   1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon it's

> `A   T   L   A   N   T   I   S       A   H
>  S   O   I   R   E   E       T   Y   L   E   R
>  T   I       O   M   N   I   A       I   R   I   S
>  A   L   A   M   O       D   I   P       E   V   E
>  X   E   N   A       R   E   N   A   L       I   N
>  A   T   E       B   O   A       S   O   L   E   A
>  N       M   O   A   N       A   S   S   O   R   T
>  T   R   I   C   K       S   I   P       R   E   E
>  H   I   C   C   U   P       R   O   B   E       S
>  I   D       U       A   A       R   A   T   S
>  N   E   I   L   A   R   M   S   T   R   O   N   G
>      R   O   T   T   E   N           K       I
>  E   S   T       A   T   E   A   S   E       P   I
>  R       A   T   M   O   S   P   H   E   R   E
>  O   F       Y   A       I   O       P   Y   R   O
>  S   A   V   A   N   N   A   H           E   S   S`

Comment: I forgot to remove a letter in row 7 from the text version. I will edit it now. Sorry. It is the I in the middle.

Comment: Ah! That makes sooo much more sense.

Comment: (I was confused by the vertical one through that I, too!)

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly.